# JAVA:Try catch Exceptions

Tags: java, try-catch

I am unsure as to the best way to throw multiple exceptions in the main method. This is the approach I have taken, I was wondering if this way is correct

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  {

        File nFile = new File("ProductData.txt");
        File file = new File("CustomerData.txt");
        File pFile = new File("PurchaseOrderDataFile.txt");
        try {
            Scanner pScan = new Scanner(pFile);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            //Makes ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier object with the month and year product array
            ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier ees = new ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier
        (1, 12, InputFileData.readProductDataFile(nFile));
            //Adds successive customer records to suppliers customer list
            for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
                ees.addNewCustomer(InputFileData.readCustomerData(scan));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
                String poByMonth = InputFileData.readPurchaseOrderDataFile(pScan); //Brings list in by months
                String[] purchaseOrder = poByMonth.split("\\s+");
                ees.startNewMonth(); //When the months are split by the @ it adds a new month
                for (int j = 0; j <= purchaseOrder.length - 1; j++) {
                    String[] result = purchaseOrder[j].split("#");
                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(result[3]);
                    ees.addNewPurchaseOrder(result[0], result[1], result[2], qty);
                    double orderTotal = 0;
                    for (Product p : ees.getRangeOfProducts()) {
                        if (p.getProductCode().equals(result[2])) {
                            orderTotal = p.getPricePerUnit() * qty;
                        }
                    }
                    CustomerDetails customer = ees.getDetails().findCustomer(result[1]);
                    customer.setTotalPrice(orderTotal + customer.getTotalPrice());
                    if (result[1].substring(0, 1).equals("P")) {
                        System.out.println("Customer ID: " + (result[1]));
                        System.out.println("Discount: " + customer.getDiscountRate());
                    }
                }
            }
        }   //Catches exceptions
        catch(IllegalCustomerIDException| IllegalProductCodeException |
                IncorrectPurchaseOrderException | CustomerNotFoundException | IOException ex){
            //Outputs exceptions if they are caught 
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have put it all in one large try catch and thrown all the exceptions at once. It seemed a nice neat way of doing it but I'm unsure as to whether or not it is good practice

Comment: Why don't you just declare that the main method throws all of those exception types?

Comment: How do I do that? if you mean put all them in the header? I got told that was bad practice

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalCustomerIDException, IllegalProductCodeException` etc.

Comment: isn't that bad practice?

Comment: On what basis do you consider it to be a bad practice? It is preserving type information about exceptions that you don't need to handle; it allows you to call this main method from code which *is* able/willing to handle them correctly without losing information about the exceptions.

Comment: So you'd say it is better than doing a try catch? I'm pretty sure I read somewhere you should never put them in your main methods header mhm

Comment: If you do not  know how to handle the exception, then there is no problem in throw all of them in the method header

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        ...
    } catch(IllegalCustomerIDException e) {
       ...
    } catch(IllegalProductCodeException e) {
       ...
    } catch(IncorrectPurchaseOrderException e) {
       ...
    } catch(CustomerNotFoundException e) {
       ...
    } catch(IOException e) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels like a big old step backwards from multicatching the exception.

Comment: This probably only makes sense if those exceptions are subclasses of each other and you want to do something specific with the exception.

Comment: Usually you catch exceptions because you know how to "handle" that exception. In this example you could do different things based in the catched exception (log or something else)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this explains when you should catch exceptions:
When i know how to handle the exceptions:

```
class SomeWeirdName{
  void someMethod(){
    try{
      // your logic here >_<
    }
    catch(ExceptionTypeA A){
      doSomething1();
    }
    catch(ExceptionTypeB B){
      doSomething2();
    }finally{
      somethingElse();
    }
  }
}
```

If I don not know how to handle the exception:

```
    class SomeWeirdName{
      // i don't know how to handle the exception, so no need to catch them
      // maybe someone else is gonna catch the exception later in some 
      // other class
      void someMethod() throws ExceptionTypeA, ExceptionTypeB{        
          // your logic here >_<
      }
    }
```

Like you see, when or how you catch the exception "should" depend on how you "handle" that exception. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could just do a `catch (Exception e){}` to catch all of them at once.

However, most of the time it's more useful to actually do something with a exception when/where it happens, instead of just catching them all at the end.

Comment: So if I did catch {Exception e}{sout"e"} it would just output the specific exception? is that much better than what I'm doing?

Comment: Catching `Exception` is rarely a good idea: it hides exceptions which you should handle in a specific way, e.g. `InterruptedException`, which you may add in later updates to the code.